# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}(1+\cos(x))^n\,dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration

During our studies on Riemann Integrals we were given the following question in my Calculus II course:

$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{let } f_n(x)=(1+\cos(x))^n, f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$$

$$\text{ Find}: \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}f_n(x)\, dx $$

I have tried finding the limit using the squeeze theorem. I noticed that the function is defined on $[0,1]$, where
$\cos(x)$ is positive and decreasing. I used the following boundaries:

$$ 1\leq f_n\leq 2^n \implies \frac{1}{2^n} = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}1 \leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}f_n(x) \leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}2^n = 1  $$

but $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\frac{1}{2^n} = 0 $ which means I'm unable to apply the squeeze theroem.

I've tried using tighter lower boundaries such as $1+\cos(1)$ But it didn't seem to work.

I did some trial and error by calculaing the integrals manually for different values of $n$ and it does seem like $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}f_n(x) dx = 1 $

This means that somehow I should find a lower bundary which tends to 1 when $n\to\infty$.
Any ideas on how to go forward from here are welcome.

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the post don't match

Comment: Expand the brackets via binomial, then use the Chebyshev polynomials. You may get further.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Thank you, I think I missed some brackets. let me know if it's alright now.

Comment: @AndrewKovács I'm unfamiliar with Chebyshev polynomials and I'm not sure if it makes sense in the context of my course. I'll try that anyway but It'll be of great help if you can write down some more elaborate explanation

Comment: Then it is a good reason to learn about that. I'm currently traveling so maybe if noone posts till then, I'll post an answer. Also the cosine function takes negative values too, so one plus cosine isn't always bigger then one.

Comment: By continuity, $\cos x\ge 1-\epsilon$ for all $|x|<\delta$, which should give a better lower bound.

Comment: @daw I agree with your claim, but I'm not sure how this would give a lower bound.

Comment: Call me naive but isn't this trivial, if x is small which it is, the first term of the series expension is only relevant which is 2^n, integrate to x, which is 2^nx fill in lower and upper bounds, gives 2^n/2^n=1.

Comment: @Gerben This is very very interesting! Thank you. It is unclear to me why Is only the first term of the series relevant here? What about the rest?

Comment: The cosinus series is 1+O(x^2), you add 1, so it's 2+O(x^2), because x is small, 2 + a little bit here O(x^2) till a big power n, is 2^n. The next part is n2^(n-1)O(x^2) which is very small. Binomial theorem. Because x is small it's neclectable. Only the biggest term is relevant, integrate to x, and it's solves it self. Just like any other integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another slightly different answer:

Since $x\mapsto \cos(s)$ monotone decreasing in $[0,\pi/2]$ and $2^{-n}\leq \tfrac2n$ for $n>2$,

$$2^{-n}\Big(1+\cos\big(\tfrac{2}{n}\big)\Big)^n\leq 2^{-n}(1+\cos(2^{-n}))^n\leq I_n:=\int^{2^{-n}}_0(1+\cos(x))^n\,dx\leq 1$$

A simple algebraic manipulation gives
$$
a_n:=2^{-n}\left(2-\Big(1-\cos\big(\tfrac2n\big)\Big)\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{n\Big(1-\cos\big(\tfrac2n\big)\Big)}{2n}\right)^n
$$

Notice that $\frac{1-\cos\big(\tfrac2n\big)}{\tfrac2n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Hence $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^0=1$

Putting things together, we gave that $\lim_nI_n=1$.

---

Here we are using a well known result that states that if $c_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}c$, then
$$\Big(1+\frac{c_n}{n}\Big)^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^c.$$

Answer (score 4):

You have $$(1+\cos x)^n\geq \left(2-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^n\geq\left(2-2^{-2n-1}\right)^n$$
on $x\in[0,2^{-n}]$
and therefore:
$$\int_0^{2^{-n}}f_n(x)dx\geq\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+2}}\right)^n\to 1.$$

Comment: Thank you, This seems like the way to go here. I'm having hard time understanding the inequalities . $(1+\cos x)^n\geq \left(2-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^n $ : You used series expansion here, right? What happend to the reminder $(O(x^4))$, why was it neglected.
I'm also not sure why $\left(2-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^n\geq\left(2-2^{-2n-1}\right)^n$

Comment: it's pretty well-known that you get upper and lower bounds if you truncate the Taylor series of a function like $\cos x$, where the series is alternating. Or you can just prove it directly by taking derivative: $g(x ) = \cos x - 1+\frac{x^2}{2}\geq 0$ for all $x.$

Comment: Thanks. That is a good way to prove it. If this is possible, than why not truncate at first order? $(1+\cos x)^n\geq 2^n$

Comment: @Yup8 A truncation is an upper bound if it ends with a $+$, and a lower bound if it ends with a $-$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

By change of variable, the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)^{n}dy.
\end{align*}
It is not hard to compute that
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{n}(y)=\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)^{n}\rightarrow 1
\end{align*}
pointwise $y\in[0,1]$.

Now we look at
\begin{align*}
F(z)=\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{z-1}}\right)\right)^{z}
\end{align*}
for large $z>0$. It is not hard to check that $F'(z)>0$ for large $z$, this implies that $(\varphi_{n})_{n}$ is an increasing sequence.

By Dini Theorem, $\varphi_{n}$ converges uniformly to $1$, now you can swipe the limit with the integral.

**EDIT:**

A useful limit here:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log(\cos x)}{-x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\cos x}\cdot-\sin x}{-2x}=\dfrac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
n\log\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)=\dfrac{\log\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)}{-\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{2}}\cdot-\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{2}\cdot n\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I've tried showing that $\begin{align*}
\varphi_{n}(y)=\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{y}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)^{n}\rightarrow 1
\end{align*}$ but I found it quite hard and had to use L'Hopital's. Would you care elaborate how would you suggest to show it ?

Comment: Take a look, I have made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the behaviour close to $x=0$ is relevant, so we need to check the contributions of higher order:
$$\int_0^{1/2^n} (1+\cos(x))^n \, {\rm d}x = \int_0^{1/2^n} (1+1+{\cal O}(x^2))^n \, {\rm d}x = 2^n \int_0^{1/2^n} (1+{\cal O}(x^2))^n \, {\rm d}x \\
= 2^n \left( 2^{-n} + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^{1/2^n} {\cal O}(x^{2k}) \, {\rm d}x \right) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{{\cal O}(4^{-nk)}}{2k+1} \, .$$

Now you can estimate the sum $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{{\cal O}(4^{-nk)}}{2k+1}\right| \leq C\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} 4^{-nk} = C \left\{ (1+4^{-n})^n - 1 \right\} \rightarrow 0$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for some constant $C>0$.